# Проверка массива с числами

Tags: c#

У меня есть массив с 9 цифрами по порядку, и пользователь вводит число, как сделать проверку на то, есть ли то число в этом массиве которое он ввел ?

Comment: Какие 9 цифр? В десятичной системе исчисления 10 цифр.

Comment: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Comment: Например, пользователь введет 23, программа должна сказать "число есть в массиве"?

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, что значит `число есть в массиве`

Comment: int[] number = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

Comment: `number.Contains(1)` или `number.Any(x=>x == 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (chislo >= 1 && chislo <= 9) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Сперва не понимал в чем суть, потом как понял, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```
        int[] numbers = new int[] { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
        int chislo; // число, которое введет пользователь
        bool isSame = false; // флаг, который проверяет совпадение числа от пользователя с числом из массива

        foreach ( int item in numbers) {
            if(item == chislo) {
                isSame = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: За вариант спасибо